# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in on line 21

Tags: php, mysqli

So I'm trying to limit the rows returned and the code works fine if i use the following SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0, 10

But once i change to SELECT * FROM survey LIMIT $startrow, 10 i get the following error,Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given on line 21, any ideas why I've tried to see what the issue and have tried multiple methods and still can't fix the issue.

```
<?php

    global $startrow;
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test") or die ("could not connect to mysql");

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM survey LIMIT $startrow, 10");

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Opinion</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($con, $result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Opinion'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    if (!isset($_GET['startrow']) or !is_numeric($_GET['startrow'])) {
      $startrow = 0;
    } else {
      $startrow = (int)$_GET['startrow'];
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The mysqli_fetch_array() function fetches a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both.

Basically replaces this loop here:

```
$query = "SELECT Lastname,Age FROM Persons ORDER BY Lastname";
$res = $con->query($query);

while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
      //do something
}
```

With this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

$sql="SELECT Lastname,Age FROM Persons ORDER BY Lastname";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 // Numeric array
 $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
 printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row[0],$row[1]);

 // Associative array
 $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row["Lastname"],$row["Age"]);

 // Free result set
 mysqli_free_result($result);

 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

So in your case you just have to take the result of the query and (since I can see you have specified you want it as associative array choose that option) it would look like this:

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
 //do something
 }
```

Comment: It only outputs one row of the database and has no column headers how can you make it print all from database

Comment: @user3509297 I edited my answer by adding  the loop so that its more clear, what to do.

Comment: So i eidited the code and it now outputs as soNegative (12-07-2018 14:58:37) Negative (12-07-2018 14:58:42) its not outputting the full name and isnt in a table <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM survey ";
    
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
     {
           $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
           printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row["Opinion"],$row["date"]);
    }
     mysqli_close($con);
    
    ?>

Comment: yes @user3509297 that is the basic idea :) If my answer helped you please upvote and select it as a "accepted answer".

Comment: how would i be able to have it as a table rather than a list. thanks for the help but it isnt outputting the full contents of the table only part

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_fetch_array  or [mysqli_result::fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) (OOP) is a function for mysqli results, not mysqli connections.

Your $result (mysqli_result object) should be the first, and likely only, argument to this function.

Answer (score 1):

You should not add `$con` to the `mysqli_fetch_array` function since what it does is, just convert the query result to an array and so it doesn't need a data base connection. For example, mysqli_query needs a database connection to get the result of query from the DB...So the resulting function to use is `mysqli_fetch_array($result)`

Answer (score 0):

Update on the question, i have now fixed the issue with thanks to users who posted. 
Answer is below for anyone who wants reference. Also set Variables for pagination and set up next and previous buttons for moving through the table
    $limit = 8;

```
    if (isset($_GET["page"] )) 
        {
        $page  = $_GET["page"]; 
        } 
    else 
       {
        $page=1; 
       };  
$index= ($page-1) * $limit;      

$sql = "SELECT * FROM survey LIMIT $index, $limit";

   $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
   echo "<div style='overflow: auto;'>";
echo "<table width=50% border=5px align=center >
<tr>
<th height=35 >Opinion</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>"; 

   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo '<tr align=center height=30 >';

                            echo "<td>" . $row['Opinion'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
     }
} 
    else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo "<a href='admin.php?page=".($page-1)."' class='button'>Previous</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
    echo "<a href='admin.php?page=".($page+1)."' class='button'>Next</a>";
```